# Mongoose aggregation with discriminator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, azure-cosmosdb

I use CosmosDB Mongo API with only one collection using discriminators.
I'm now facing a problem where I want to "join" other collections into one.
My common collection is named "alldata" and has discriminator keys (_type) "Session", "Room" and "User".

Session contains "roomId" and "speakerIds" (Array of user ids).

Session object:

```
{
  "singleEntrance": false,
  "accreditationRequired": false,
  "closed": false,
  "usersAtended": [],
  "speakerIds": [
    "5b573723930d9751768f266e",
    "5b586b6032063a70632721d8"
  ],
  "archived": false,
  "_type": "Session",
  "_id": "5b586f81ae744a7266524f84",
  "title": "Bla bla",
  "about": "",
  "type": "SIS1",
  "track": "Special Interest Session",
  "venue": "Bla 1",
  "roomId": "5b5731e764f0de4f9e4082ac",
  "from": "2018-10-22T10:00:00.015Z",
  "to": "2018-10-22T12:00:00.015Z"
}
```

Result I want:

```
{
  "singleEntrance": false,
  "accreditationRequired": false,
  "closed": false,
  "usersAtended": [],
  "spikeri": [
    {* LIST OF USER OBJECTS *}
  ],
  "archived": false,
  "_type": "Session",
  "_id": "5b586f81ae744a7266524f84",
  "title": "Bla bla",
  "about": "",
  "type": "SIS1",
  "track": "Special Interest Session",
  "venue": "Bla 1",
  "room": {
            "_id": "5b5731e764f0de4f9e4082ac",
            "archived": false,
            "_type": "Room",
            "name": "Bla 1",
            "location": "Hotel Bla",
            "createdAt": "2018-07-24T14:04:23.370Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-07-24T14:04:23.370Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
  "from": "2018-10-22T10:00:00.015Z",
  "to": "2018-10-22T12:00:00.015Z"
}
```

Room works fine, but I just cannot get User ("speakers") to work.
Finally, here's the code:

```
async getAgenda() {
    return await Session.aggregate([
        {
            // this query returns all Sessions...
            $match: {
                $and: [
                    { from: { $gte: new Date("2018-10-22T10:00:00.015Z") } },
                    { to: { $lte: new Date("2018-10-22 17:00:00.015Z") } },
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: { from: "alldata", localField: "roomId", foreignField: "_id", as: "room" }
        },
        {
            $unwind: { path: '$room' }
        },
        {
            $lookup: { from: "alldata", localField: "speakerIds", foreignField: "_id", as: "spikeri" }
        }
    ])
}
```

**Update: User object (speaker == User):**

```
{
        "_id": "5b2ba7784ad0f226d8ae2788",
        "group": "USER",
        "verified": true,
        "eventsRegistered": [
            "5b2b77b74ad0f226d8ae2780",
            "5b27ca01cc7eff056826acc7"
        ],
        "eventsAttended": [],
        "tickets": [
            "5b27cc43cc7eff056826accb",
            "5b27d284cc7eff056826acd1",
            "5b27cceecc7eff056826acd0"
        ],
        "contacts": [],
        "meetings": [],
        "_type": "User",
        "email": "bla@blabla.us",
        "password": "...",
        "countryCode": "HR",
        "firstName": "Blaman",
        "lastName": "Bla bla",
        "role": "SPEAKER",
        "createdAt": "2018-06-21T13:26:16.686Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-07-25T14:21:42.055Z",
        "__v": 0
        "confirmationCode": "5375159",
        "transactionIds": [
            "..."
        ],
        "transactionId": "...",
        "gender": "",
        "jobTitle": "",
        "companyAddress": "",
        "companyName": "",
        "postalCode": "",
        "city": "",
        "country": "Croatia"
    }
```

Thank you for help in advance!

Comment: Can you show a sample document from the `speakers` collection?

Comment: P.S. don't forget, that you can't compare `ObjectID` with `String` (-;

Comment: hey, i know i can't compare them, all _id are ObjectIds in Mongo, that's why Room works. 
I added User object too

Comment: For me it works, it means that the problem is in the details of your query.

Comment: Or your sample data is different from real

Comment: Are you using CosmosDB too?

Comment: Have you ever figure it our, I am having same problem right now with cosmosDB and trying to populate, but in multiple collections under discriminator use same field name.

Comment: @noitse nope, haven't figured it out yet. I'm doing complex queries manually for now and caching the results for better performance

Comment: @pavle I gave up from cosmosDB for now, I am using MongoDB for dev environment until release, then I'll figure it out. One solution is to do populate on results. But I just don't like that approach. Hopefully, they will upgrade their MongoDB server to 3.6 on CosmosDB, so we can use let and graphLookup

Comment: @noitse I'll migrate to MongoDB in the near future too